# Hidden text box in report SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, report

Can anyone help please, I am trying to make a textbox hidden within a report when certain criteria is met.

I can get it to work when I have a single parameter as below

=IIF(InStr(Fields!DeliveryCompany.Value,"zzzzz")>0, false,true)

I need to add another and this is where it falls down

=IIF((InStr(Fields!DeliveryCompany.Value,"zzzzz")>0, false + IIF(InStr(Fields!DeliveryCompany.Value,"yyyy")>0, false), true

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"+" either performs addition or concatenates strings, so your syntax is incorrect. See [Operators in Expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/operators-in-expressions-report-builder-and-ssrs)

I believe what you are looking for is something like this:

```
=IIf(
    (InStr(Fields!DeliveryCompany.Value, "zzzzz") > 0)
    AND
    (InStr(Fields!DeliverCompany.Value, "yyyy") > 0)
    , false
    , true
)
```

If you only need one of those conditions to match then just swap the AND for an OR.

Comment: Brilliant, Thanks very much